# SvgAnimatedString missing method indexOf

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angularjs

I am using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) together with [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/). When use hyperlink in svg object(which rendered through angular directive), I am getting this error.

[image]

As per the doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/SVGAnimatedString), svgAnimatedString doesn't have any specific method. How can I solve this. Can I inject a method or any other way.

Part of the code below. Thanks you.

```
svg.selectAll("a.node")
                        .data(data)
                        .enter().append("a")
                        .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("xlink:href", "test")
                        .append("rect")
```

Comment: Looks like you're passing in a DOM element where the function is expecting something else as its argument. You're going to need to provide more code to get an answer, though - how are you applying the Angular function?

Comment: @nrabinowitz thanks. I will come up with more details. I am not calling angular directly though, it try to parse the url when I click on svg link. Thanks again, I will get back to you.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DEvDe/1/ . If you open web developer, and click on the cirlce. it gives the above error. thanks.

Comment: Similar problem with other methods, e.g. className - I sent a [PR to piwik](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/8346).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various libraries have encountered this problem (i.e [here](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3/commit/7ab5e3567f6c5976c90e30d13e5b6ee3890590f1)). In SVG, when you try to get the href attribute of an anchor it returns an `SVGAnimatedString`. You get the actual string by using `SVGAnimatedString.baseVal`. I don't know how you can do this without patching Angular, but this will give you an idea of what is needed:

```
  this.$$rewriteAppUrl = function(absoluteLinkUrl) {
     if (absoluteLinkUrl.baseVal != null) {
        absoluteLinkUrl = absoluteLinkUrl.baseVal;
     }
    if(absoluteLinkUrl.indexOf(appBaseUrl) == 0) {
      return absoluteLinkUrl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's better to use `xx.baseVal.hasOwnProperty('baseVal')` instead of `xx.baseVal != null`

Answer (score 6):

If you must deal with a library which doesn't handle SVG graphics, you can use something like the following to define split on the SVGAnimatedString.  Rinse and repeat for other string prototype methods.

```
 // Set a split prototype on the SVGAnimatedString object which will return the split of the baseVal on this
 // SVGAnimatedString instance
 SVGAnimatedString.prototype.split = function(){ return String.prototype.split.apply(this.baseVal, arguments); };
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple Shim to get it working with the existing code:

```
SVGAnimatedString.prototype.toString = function () { return this.baseVal; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem without using d3. I'm using only pure SVG and appending it into DOM with angularJS controller. Problem isn't in d3. You can fix this problem with adding return false value into jQuery click event handler on elements that contains link.

Part of my SVG:

```
<g id="1" class="node">
<a xlink:title="title">
<polygon fill="#cccccc" stroke="#cccccc" points="25,-434 25,-457 98,-457 98,-434 25,-434"></polygon>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="25,-434 25,-457 98,-457 98,-434 25,-434"></polygon>
<text text-anchor="start" x="29.5" y="-442.3" font-family="Arial" font-size="14.00">title</text>
<polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" points="25,-412 25,-434 98,-434 98,-412 25,-412"></polygon>
<text text-anchor="start" x="37" y="-419.8" font-family="Arial" font-size="14.00">title</text>
</a>
</g>
```

jQuery overloading method:

```
$('g.node').click(function (element) {
   return false;
});
```

Hope this helps...