# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGAnimatedString> has no method 'indexOf' in d3.js and jquery UI mobile when trying to show a popup

Tags: jquery-mobile, d3.js

I'm trying to build a d3 chart in a mobile application with force directed graph, where the nodes should show a popup on touch. 
However, on clicking on the nodes, i get the following error -

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'indexOf'

I've recreated the issue on codepen -

http://codepen.io/madhug/pen/gdiKr

I tried googling for this, but it seems like the bug was fixed (?) - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/78

Am i missing something? What should i be looking for to troubleshoot this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue like this: [SvgAnimatedString missing method indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588913/svganimatedstring-missing-method-indexof)

I have same problem without using d3. I'm using only pure SVG and appending it into DOM with angularJS controller. Problem isn't in d3. You can fix this problem with adding return false value into jQuery click event handler on elements that contains link.

Part of my SVG:

```
<g id="1" class="node">
<a xlink:title="title">
<polygon fill="#cccccc" stroke="#cccccc" points="25,-434 25,-457 98,-457 98,-434 25,-434"></polygon>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="25,-434 25,-457 98,-457 98,-434 25,-434"></polygon>
<text text-anchor="start" x="29.5" y="-442.3" font-family="Arial" font-size="14.00">title</text>
<polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" points="25,-412 25,-434 98,-434 98,-412 25,-412"></polygon>
<text text-anchor="start" x="37" y="-419.8" font-family="Arial" font-size="14.00">title</text>
</a>
</g>
```

jQuery overloading method:

```
$('g.node').click(function (element) {
   return false;
});
```

Hope this helps...